# Python Organise contents of a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file which holds contents such as:

```
IMAGE_[A0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00002.jpg
```

I need it to be organised such as:

```
IMAGE_[A0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00002.jpg
```

How would I do this, using python 3x?

Comment: `sorted()` is your friend. Read the file as lines, sort it, write it back.

Comment: Would it not just end up sorting the A0 files together and then B0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort using a key, then write back to file:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = sorted(f.read().splitlines(), key=lambda x: (x[11:16], x[7:9]))
    print('\n'.join(data))
```

Output:

```
IMAGE_[A0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00002.jpg
```

Comment: This won't prevent `IMAGE_[A1]_00001.jpg` from coming before `IMAGE_[A0]_00001.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

Your items are named like `IMAGE_`x`_`y`.jpg`. They are now sorted by (x, y), you need sorting by (y, x).

This can be done e.g. by a regular expression:

```
import re

# group 1 is things like `[A0]`, group 2, like `00001`.
name_rx = re.compile('IMAGE_(.*)_(.*)\\.jpg')

def sort_key(s):
  match = rx_.match(s)
  if match:
    return (match.group(2), match.group(1))  # reverse parts
  else:
    return (x, x)  # Natural order for those who don't match.

new_list = sorted(old_list, key=sort_key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` and `sorted`:

```
import re
import string
def key_param(d):
   a, b= re.findall('(?<=\[)\w+(?=\])|\d+(?=\.jpg)', d)
   return [int(b)]+[int(i) if i.isdigit() else string.ascii_uppercase.index(i) for i in a]

file_data = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]

new_data = sorted(file_data, key=key_param)
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('\n'.join(new_data))
```

Output:

```
IMAGE_[A0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00001.jpg
IMAGE_[A0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[A1]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B0]_00002.jpg
IMAGE_[B1]_00002.jpg
```